I need to create a card structure but I don't know how to do it
The card structure I want to make

I tried to do something as I specified in my code, but it was not exactly what I wanted.
For example, I get overflow errors etc. even though I specify horizontal.
Is using listTile the wrong decision here
SizedBox(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: campSites.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Map<String, dynamic> campSite = campSites[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 99,
                  width: 94,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: campSite['image'],
                      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: imageProvider,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      placeholder: (context, url) =>
                          const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                          const Icon(Icons.error),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(campSite['name'],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  subtitle: Text('${campSite['location']} away'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );


you don't need ListTile for that you can use column and row.

this is supposed to be a scrollable structure, it has 5 elements

the ListTile has nothing to do with scrolling.

Please try PageView + Row
See the example for more information
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageViewExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    final chunkItems = items.slices(2).toList();
    const spacePerItem = 16.0;
    final itemWidth =
        (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - spacePerItem * 3) / 2;
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: chunkItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Row(children: [
        const SizedBox(width: spacePerItem / 2),
        ...chunkItems[index].map(
          (e) => Container(
            width: itemWidth,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: spacePerItem / 2),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text('$e'),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: spacePerItem / 2),
      ]),
    );
  }
}


It seems like you are trying to create a card structure for displaying campsite information using Flutter. The code you provided is on the right track, but if you are facing overflow errors, you might need to adjust the sizing and layout of your widgets.
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: campSites.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    Map<String, dynamic> campSite = campSites[index];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 120, // Adjust the height as needed
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          color: Colors.grey[200], // Add background color if 
needed
        ),
        child: Row(
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: campSite['image'],
            width: 100, // Adjust the width of the image
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: (context, url) => const 
CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                campSite['name'],
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
               ),
                subtitle: Text('${campSite['location']} away'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),

